# Find $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $(f - 1)\Delta f + f^2 = 0$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

I wish to solve the following nonlinear PDE that I derived in statistical physics. (I was curious if I could include higher order terms into a model for heat transfer described in a homework problem.) Find a function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ parametrized in spherical coordinates s.t.
$$(f - 1) \Delta f + f^2 = 0$$
where I have suppressed the argument $(r, \theta, \phi)$ to $f$ for brevity.

If I try a spherical harmonic, I have that $\Delta f = 0$, so that $f^2 = 0$ and $f$ vanishes identically. Likewise, if $f$ solves the Helmholtz equation, we have $\Delta f = -k^2 f$ and $-k^2 f(f-1) + f^2 = 0$ which also fails to yield a useful solution.

Is there an ansatz that I may choose to reduce the problem into a linear equation. I remember from quantum physics that a certain nonlinear PDE arising from the time independent Schrodinger equation in a Harmonic potential could be made linear by multiplying an unknown function by the asymptotic behavior. In that case, $f(u) = g(u) \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)$ was the required solution. Here, however, I am having difficulty getting an idea of the asymptotic behavior. Could I assume invariance with respect to $\theta$ and $\phi$ and try to find asymptotic behavior for $r$? Can this equation be transformed into a well known nonlinear PDE? (I had actually noticed that in the 1D rectangular case, the equation bares some resemblance to a Sturm-Liouville problem.)

**An Instructive Mistake:** I have been trying to investigate if the original equation satisfies the Painleve criterion via Mathematica, but have been unsuccessful in getting a definitive result. I am willing to broaden my search for a solution $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb C$. I recall a [certain paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00776157/document) that I read while studying quantum physics, which made a rather bold claim (given that no stipulations were put on $G$) about solving certain classes of PDEs.

> Let $G : \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$ be any real valued function and consider the generalized Schrodinger equation
> $$i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + G(-\hbar^2\Delta)\psi = 0$$
> will have a solution
> $$\psi(x,t) = e^{-itG(-\hbar^2\Delta)} \psi_0(x)$$
> because
> $$\mathcal F(G(-\hbar^2 \Delta)\psi)(p) = G(|p|^2) \hat \psi(p)$$
> acts as a Fourier multiplier.

With this in mind, I could manipulate my initial equation as

$$
\begin{align}
(f-1)\Delta f + f^2 &= 0 \\
f\Delta f + f^2 &= \Delta f \\
\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta f + f} &= f \\
\underbrace{\left(\frac{\Delta}{\Delta + 1}\right)}_{G(\Delta)} f &= f 
\end{align}
$$

and define $F(r,\theta,\phi,t) = \upsilon(t)f(r,\theta,\phi)$ after neglecting constants by

$$
\begin{align}
F(r,\theta,\phi,t) &= \exp\left(-it\left(\frac{\Delta}{\Delta+1}\right)\right)f_0(r,\theta,\phi) \\
& = \exp\left(-itG(\Delta)\right)f_0(r,\theta,\phi)
\end{align}
$$

Could I treat the above like a flow to prove that constant phase shifts of the equation remain valid if we allow it to take complex values? I did not think that this result would be trivial because the powers of $f$ are not the same throughout the equation.

**Correction:** As @Zachary mentioned in the comments, this method fails because $G$ is a nonlinear function.

**Update:** I numerically integrated this equation under a variety of initial conditions and observed horrible ill-conditioning and poor stability. I have decided to accept the answer that no desirable solution to the equation exists.

Comment: Hello. Just a quick comment that the Schrodinger equation with harmonic potential is already linear. That transformation does not change whether it is linear or not.

Comment: @Zachary Yes, you're correct. I will edit my equation to say Schrodinger-like. There were certain assumptions that prevented it from being linear. I think there was a $\Psi^2$ term somewhere in the equation. Thank you for reading my question so closely. Do you think I could try a Painleve test or form a Lax pair for the system?

Comment: Is it true that $$\frac{\Delta}{\Delta+1} f=\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta f+f}?$$ I suspect not. The rescaling $f\mapsto \lambda f$ taking $\lambda\to\infty$ will show you why.

Comment: @Zachary I'm sorry; I don't quite follow. I was treating "1" as the identity operator, but now in hindsight I probably should have used the function $\text{id}$. I was trying to define $\frac{\Delta}{\Delta + 1}$ to be a stand-in for the operator that would produce $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta f + f}$ when applied to $f$. Should I try to notate it as $\left(\frac{\Delta}{\Delta + \text{id}}\right)$, or did I make some glaring conceptual mistake? Thank you for all of your guidance.

Comment: The issue is when you write it that way, it seems to imply another meaning, not the one you are giving it. The fourier multiplication theorem you state is not useful in your case because your expression is non-linear in $f$ and you cannot easily take its Fourier transform.

Comment: So when the paper I cited says _any_ real valued function, it really meant to say any _linear_ real valued function? I thought that was a bit of a stretch, but I didn't know enough to be able to reject it. Thanks again.

Comment: Side rmk: the Ansatz $f:=u(r)$, that is, radial solutions, produces the ODE for $u(r)$
$$ \ddot u +\frac2r\dot u =\frac{u^2}{u-1}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple observations at least rule out certain types of "nice" solutions. First of all, if $f=1$ anywhere, then $\Delta f$ must be singular. Moreover, if either $f>1$ or $f<1$, then $\Delta f$ has a sign opposite to $f-1$. So, if $f>1$, there cannot be a minimum of $f$, and if $f<1$, there cannot be a maximum. What qualitative properties do you require or expect?

Comment: Could I produce a Lax pair for the system? I've been working for the last two hours to set up a Painleve test in Wolfram mathematica to determine if that would be a worthy avenue of pursuit. A solution to this equation will present me with a generalization of spherical Harmonics, which in turn could be used as a "stationary state" for my original problem in statistical physics. Could I try to contact you via the chat?