# Is the Fourier multiplier $\mathcal F(G(-\hbar^2 \Delta)\psi)(p) = G(|p|^2)\hat \psi(p)$ justified for any real function $G$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I am confused about a claim asserted in the paper ["Higher Order Schrodinger Equations"](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00776157/document) published in IOP Science. The authors claim that a Fourier multiplier identity

$$
\mathcal F(G(-\hbar^2 \Delta)\psi)(p) = G(|p|^2)\hat \psi(p)
$$

is valid for any real function $G$. I was initially dubious but decided to believe them on account of the prestige I accredited to IOP Science. Upon asking about this claim in another [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437500/find-f-mathbb-r3-to-mathbb-r-s-t-f-1-delta-f-f2-0), I was kindly informed that the identity only holds for linear $G$. The authors, however, also claim that an exact solution in terms of Fourier multipliers holds for the semirelativistic equation $G(y) = -\sqrt{c^2 y + m^2 c^4}$. They then use this solution later in the paper to prove a bound on the power series approximation
$$G(y) = -mc^2 + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\alpha(n)}{m^{2n - 1} c^{2n-2}}(-y)^n$$
within its radius of convergence. What am I missing here? Is it really possible for them to treat ***any*** real valued function as a Fourier multiplier? If that were possible, then why would they be using a power series approximation in the first place?

I quoted the passage for ease of reading.

> **Solving a generalized Schrodinger equation:** Let $G:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$ be  real-valued function, and consider the generalized Schrodinger equation.
> $$
> i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + G(-\hbar^2 \Delta) \psi = 0
> $$
> (3.18)
> The quantity $G(-\hbar^2 \Delta) \psi$ is defined a s a Fourier multiplier:
> $$
> \mathcal F(G(-\hbar^2 \Delta)\psi)(p) = G(|p|^2)\hat \psi(p)
> $$
> The most important aspect is that we want to encompass the following three cases.
>
> - Schrodinger equation: $G(y) = \frac{-1}{2m} y$.
> - Semi-relativistic equation (3.3): $G(y) = -\sqrt{c^2 y + m^2 c^4}$
> - Higher order Schrodinger equation  (3.9):
>   $$G(y) = -mc^2 + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\alpha(n)}{m^{2n - 1} c^{2n-2}}(-y)^n$$
>   Applying the Fourier transform to (3.18) with respect to the space variable, we obtain formally a first order ordinary differential equation in time for $\hat \psi$, in view of Proposition (2.1):
>   $$i\hbar \frac{\partial \hat \psi}{\partial t} + G(|p|^2) \hat \psi = 0$$
>   $$\hat \psi(0, p) = \hat \psi_0(p)$$
>   It is solved explicitly:
>   $$\hat \psi(p,t) = \hat \psi_0 (p) e^{-it G(|p|^2)}$$
>   Since $G$ is real-valued, $|\hat \psi(p,t)| = |\hat \psi_0(p)|$, and we obtain, from Proposition 2.1.

> **Proposition: 3.4** Let $s\in\mathbb R$ and $\psi_0\in H ^s(\mathbb R^d)$. Then the Cauchy problem (3.18) has a unique solution $\psi \in C(\mathbb R; H^s (\mathbb R^d))$, denoted by
> $$\psi(t) = e^{-itG(-\hbar^2\Delta)}\psi_0$$
> It is given by (3.19). Moreover, we have
> $$\|\psi(\cdot, t)\|_{H^s} = \|\psi_0\|_{H^s}$$
> for all $t \in \mathbb R$. In other words, the propagator $e^{-itG(-\hbar^2 \Delta)}$ is unitary on every Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb R^d)$.

Comment: I assume you're making a reference to my comment on your linked question. I think you missed the point that the expression $G(-\hbar^2\Delta)\psi$ must be linear in $\psi$ to be able to take the fourier transform. The restriction is not on the function $G$, as you seem to think. In that question, I commented, that for example, the expression $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta f+f}$ is not linear in $f$ so this result does not apply.

Comment: The quoted section says that that is the *definition* of the nonlocal operator $G(-\hbar^{2}\Delta)$; it is defined by its action in Fourier space, and that is standard in mathematical physics.  I suppose that you would want to show that, e.g. $\Delta\left[\left(\frac{1}{\Delta}\right)\psi\right]=\psi$, but that is completely straightforward.

Comment: @Zachary, Thank you. How could one define $G_s(-\hbar^2 \Delta)$ for $G_s(y) = -\sqrt{c^2 y + m^2 c^4}$? Would that not also yield an expression that is nonlinear in $\psi$? I don't understand how a nonlinear function $G_s(y)$ could produce a operator $G_s(-\hbar^2\Delta)$ that is linear in $\psi$. When $G$ is a power series, $-\hbar\Delta$ is directly substituted into the equation to produce the higher order Schrodinger equation. I had believed that the authors were claiming that a similar property would hold for any real function $G$. Because that is not the case, is it possible to produce a

Comment: formula for $G(-\hbar^2\Delta)$ when $G(y) = -\sqrt{c^2 y + m^2 c^4}$ or $G(y) = \frac{x}{a+x}$ where $a$ is a constant? Even if a closed form solution is not available is there an expression in terms of an integral or series that would be useful? Would you consider this problem to be in functional analysis or the theory of Fourier transforms? Any reading material would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To make sense of your Fourier multiplier, you need only to assume that $p\mapsto G(\vert p\vert^2)$ is a temperate distribution on $\mathbb R^d$. It is true whenever $G$ is a continuous function increasing at most polynomially at infinity: indeed if $\phi$ is a test function in the Schwartz space you may define
$$
\langle G(\vert p\vert^2),\phi(p)\rangle_{\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^d), \mathscr S(\mathbf R^d)}=\int_{\mathbb R^d} G(\vert p\vert^2)\phi(p) dp.
$$
Once you know that $G(\vert p\vert^2)$ is a temperate distribution on $\mathbb R^d$, you may define the product
$G(\vert p\vert^2)\hat \psi(p)$ as a temperate distribution for any $\psi$ in the Schwartz space and thus take the inverse Fourier transform of
$G(\vert p\vert^2)\hat \psi(p)$ as a temperate distribution.

Well it is probably too general (even the though the hypotheses on $G$ can be weakened), but my point is that you have to pay attention to the growth rate of $G$ at infinity. A slightly different point of view, a sort of continued abstract nonsense escape course, is to require that $p\mapsto G(\vert p\vert^2)$ belongs to the space $\mathscr O_M(\mathbb R^d)$, coined by Schwartz as the space of multiplier: a function $f$ belongs to that space when it is $C^\infty$ with all derivatives increasing at most polynomially at infinity. Then it is easy to show that
$$
\mathscr S(\mathbb R^d)\ni\phi\mapsto f\phi\in \mathscr S(\mathbb R^d)
$$
is a continuous mapping and thus by transposition
$$
\mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)\ni T\mapsto f T\in \mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)
$$
is a (weakly)
continuous mapping so that $G(\vert p\vert^2) T(p)$ belongs to $ \mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)$ for any $T\in \mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)$; thus you can define the inverse Fourier transform of $G(\vert p\vert^2) \hat T(p)$ for any $T\in \mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)$ .